# Selenium Headless Chrome and Language Setup

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

i'm working with selenium and the chrome driver in python. I can setup the language of my chrome browser like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
```

This works like a charm, but as soon as i add the headless argument i get results in german again:

```python
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Using [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) to set the language pass the *`--lang`* command using an instance of *`Options()`* as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--lang=en_US')
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Issue 1925: Expose content settings in headless mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925#c10)

Answer (score 0):

there is no tags for debian but still, maybe it will help someone.

1. Installed the `web browser - language packs`.
   The package is called `chromium-l10n` on Debian 11.
2. Made sure the locale i want is shown via `locale -a` (uncomment in `/etc/locale.gen` and use `locale-gen`).
3. Started the python program via:

   ```bash
   LANGUAGE=de programname.py
   ```

   - as alternative, setting `LANGUAGE`
     inside the python also worked.

     ```py
     from os import environ

     environ['LANGUAGE'] = 'de'
     ```

This made it work in Headless mode.