# How can i set browser language in Selenide using Java?

Tags: java, maven, selenide

Hello guys please how can i do it?When i run not headless mode browser is in english and everything works fine, but when i run headless mode language is changed to my native language.

I am using this for headless mode.

```
   Configuration.headless = true;
```

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980736/selenium-headless-chrome-and-language-setup)  that may help you

Comment: This is from Selenium and not from Selenide so it won't but thanks anyway.

Comment: https://selenide.org/javadoc/current/com/codeborne/selenide/Configuration.html i refer document from here, dude 

Comment: I found this documentation but dont know how to use it, thats why i ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenide [Configuration](https://github.com/selenide/selenide/blob/master/statics/src/main/java/com/codeborne/selenide/Configuration.java) class contains
`public static MutableCapabilities browserCapabilities` which is used by the driver for browser startup, if provided.

**For Chrome**:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
    .setHeadless(true)
    .addArguments("--lang=en_US");
Configuration.browserCapabilities = options;
```

But note `--lang` argument might be ignored on Linux.

**For Firefox**:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
    .setHeadless(true)
    .setProfile(profile);
Configuration.browserCapabilities = options;
```